# Angular nested directive communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="searchController" searchbar>
   <input type="text" id="searchfield" ng-model="myVar">
   <div searchresult>
       <div ng-repeat="data in data.menu | filter: myVar">
           {{data.title}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There is one controller called `searchController`, and 2 directives called `searchbar` and `searchresult`.

How can I have the `searchbar` directive to run a function in `searchresult` directive? I was thinking to put `require: "^searchresult"` in `searchbar` directive and call it's function. Is that the correct way of doing? What if the `searchresult` is not available there?

**Here is the detail scenario:**

When user type in the input field, the search result update by the filter. Therefore the height of `searchresult` div is changed.

How can the `searchresult` directive knows about the changes of the height & run the required function instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchResult` can have reference to `searchBar` not the other way around. As from documentation

> ^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element and its
>   parents. Throw an error if not found.

Also look at `^?` for optional dependencies. See [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) documentation.

If you detail your scenario, we can help better.

**Update**: Based on the scenario that you have outlined, you can directly watch `myVar` property in searchresult directive and whenever it changes you can trigger the function to resize the results.

Assuming that the searchresult directive does not create isolated scope. You can try, such a code inside your directive link function

```
scope.$watch('myVar',function(newValue) {
   $timeout(function() {
       //do some work here
   },0);
});
```

Timeout helps as we cannot be sure when the rendering of the list is complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated the question with detail scenario and I have stuck here for few days already. Hope you can give a help here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. But how can I watch `myVar`? How can I ensure that the function is triggered only after the result is being filtered & updated to new height? It would be great if you could show an example of code for better understanding.